# Oracle is using both full table scan instead of index scan

Tags: sql, oracle11g, query-optimization, database-performance

i am joining two tables and i have index on both columns but still oracle chooses full table scan on both instead of index scan.

i have mentioned below the query

SELECT * FROM Table 1, Table2 WHERE   Tab1_col= Tab2_col

and here it can been seen in execution plan that it is going on Full table scan

[image]

Comment: Can you please post DDL, and sample data? It may be that there's low cardinality in tab1_col and tab2_col (e.g if they're both "yes/no" fields).

Comment: If you have not run statistics on these tables recently, that is always the first thing to try.  It's the database equivalent of "Did you plug it in?"

Comment: If you have no filter - just a (implicit) join condition - and are selecting all the columns, as you've shown, then that's likely to be the most efficient plan. Using an index and then having to go and look at each table row anyway would be more work. Why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: There's no filter! A table scan is actually much better than an index scan in cases like this one.